# Selenium IDE excluding nested spans when asserting text

Tags: selenium-ide

I want to assert on text but NOT the nested span - is this possible?

I have the following HTML:

```
<span id="yui_3_15_0_3_1429668403358_1935" class="instancename">
1 Activity 0LP0
<span class="accesshide ">
 Assignment
</span>
</span>
```

I have tried this:

```
<tr>
<td>assertText</td>
<td>//div/h3[.='Topic ${TopicNumber}']/../ul/li/div/div/div/div/a/span/</td>
<td>1 Activity ${Tracker}</td>
</tr>
```

This does work though (and is not what I want):

```
<tr>
<td>assertText</td>
<td>//div/h3[.='Topic ${TopicNumber}']/../ul/li/div/div/div/div/a/span/</td>
<td>1 Activity ${Tracker} Assignment</td>
</tr>
```

But it does not work. I'd like to NOT include the extra nested span, any ideas without resorting to clever javascript?

Thanks in advance for your assistance ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately assertText uses textContent which is going to return that entire string "1 Activity ${Tracker} Assignment".
But you should be able to use a glob to check this "1 Activity ${Tracker} *"